# searching the longest series of same string in the row

Tags: python, algorithm

Hi i need to find a longest series of same number in a row

```
list = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6]

answer(`number 1 was 4 times in a row`)
```

[przyklad.txt](https://github.com/pasjonatprogramowania/przyklad.txt/blob/main/przyklad.txt)

I write my own version of this algorithm, but it returns `6024` instead of `198` (this is a true answer). This is my exam task algorithmic, and I don't understand how this algorithm needs to work. Can someone explain me this or give a link to a solution to my problem ?

orginal

```
with open('przyklad.txt','r') as plik:
    wiersze = plik.read().splitlines()
    dane = []
    pomciag = 1
    ciag = 1
    for w in wiersze:
        dane = w.split()
        for i in range(len(dane)-1):
            a = dane[i]
            b = dane[i+1]
            if a == b:
                pomciag += 1
            elif pomciag > ciag:
                ciag = pomciag
                pomciag = 1
        if pomciag > ciag:
            ciag = pomciag
            pomciag = 1
    print(ciag)
```

translated

```
with open('przyklad.txt','r') as file:
    verse = file.read().splitlines()
    date = []
    helpSeries = 1
    series = 1
    for w in verse:
        date = w.split()
        for i in range(len(date) - 1):
            a = date[i]
            b = date[i + 1]
            if a == b:
                helpSeries += 1
            elif helpSeries > series:
                series = helpSeries
                helpSeries = 1
        if helpSeries > series:
            series = helpSeries
            helpSeries = 1
    print(series)
```

Comment: can you explain the variable names plz

Comment: Why are you printing `max(a)` instead of `ciag`?

Comment: `pomciag = 1` needs to happen whenever `a != b` in your innermost loop (and at the start of each outer loop iteration)

Comment: why do you say 198 is the correct result for your input? Don't you count consecutive zeros as a valid series?

Comment: The second line in that file has 318 zeroes, and that is the maximum repetition in the whole file. Yimin's answer below is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

the pomciag variable should be refreshed inside the for loop if you want the algo to find the longest series of same number in a row. Otherwise, it will continue to plus 1, that is why the result shows 6024

Comment: The correct answer.